# How to check if a value in an Array is contained in the same array as its following one

Tags: java, arrays, string

In my Java program I have a String array of String arrays containing 3 values each.

```
String[][] actions = 
                {
                    new String[]{"R", "R'", "R2"}, 
                    new String[]{"L", "L'", "L2"}, 
                    new String[]{"D", "D'", "D2"}, 
                    new String[]{"U", "U'", "U2"}, 
                    new String[]{"F", "F'", "F2"}, 
                    new String[]{"B", "B'", "B2"}
                };
```

Now I'm letting a randomizer pick 25 values out of these arrays by random and saving the results in a normal String array (let's call it results). Now I want to check if value 0 in results is contained in the same Array as value 1, meaning if value 0 is "U" and value 1 is "U'" it should re-roll the randomizer for value 1, ignoring the array value 0 is in. In the end I'd like to have an array of Strings where no String is in the same array as its following one.

Comment: Are *all* your arrays of the form `{"x", "x", "x2"}` just for different values of `x` for each array? I have to say I'm finding your question pretty hard to understand...

Comment: I'm still lost. You have an array of string arrays. You are going to select 25 values randomly from this 2 dimensional array. Then you are going to iterate over your array of 25 values, and compare value at index i with (i+1). if they are different, you want to re-roll by picking from the 2 dimensional array?

Comment: @coffeeaddict Let's say results[i] = "R" and results[i + 1] = "R2". They both are in the same array. I don't want two values in the same array coming directly after each other in the results array, thus I'd like to re-roll the randomizer for results[i + 1] so that it gives a value from a different array.

Comment: It's a Rubik's cube move generator, and if one move in the sequence is to, say, turn the right face (R), you don't want the next move to either be to turn it the opposite way (R') or all the way around (R2). I think the best way would be to keep track of which array the last one came from, and avoid selecting another one from it again, rather than detecting the problem after the fact and re-rolling.

Comment: @DavidConrad yeah, exactly! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you might be looking for something like this?

```
public void mainMethod() {

    ...

    for(int i=0; i<(results.length-1); i++) {
      compare(results, i);  
    }
}

private void compare(String[] results, int index) {
   // compare if both values are in the same array
   if(getRowIndex(results[index]) == getRowIndex(results[index+1])) {
         reRoll(results, (index+1)); // reroll if so
         compare(results, index); // revalidate in case it re-rolls to the same array value
   }
}

private void reRoll(String[] results, int index) {
    //TODO
}

private void getRowIndex(...) {
    //TODO
}
```

The final two methods are up to how you want to implement it. There are many ways...